# OAuth получение токена CURL

Tags: oauth, curl, api, php

Получаю первый опыт работы с CURL, решил сразу за сложный проджект взяться, получить количество посещений с метрики. Для этого нужно авторизироваться на яндексе, выбрал метод по логину и паролю. Делаю так ([документация](http://api.yandex.ru/oauth/doc/dg/reference/resource-owner-credentials.xml)):

```
<?php
$url = 'https://oauth.yandex.ru/token';
$login = 'umur';
$pass = '123';
$id = 'f5aaКОДID09853427c8c1244850357a899';
$header = array('POST /token HTTP/1.1','Host: oauth.yandex.ru','Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Length: 64');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'grant_type=password&client_id=$id&username=$login&password=$pass');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
$query = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($query);
?>
```

Но при Content-Length: 64, выходит ошибка:

> `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Vary: Accept-Language Content-Type: application/json Content-Language: ru Cache-Control: no-store Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2011 10:10:27 GMT Server: lighttpd/1.4.26 {"error": "invalid_client_credentials"}`

А при Content-Length: 65 зависание на более чем 30 секунд, в следствие:

> `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in Z:\home\test\www\index.php on line 17`

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

1. $header = array(**'POST /token HTTP/1.1'** - выделенное жирным - не нужно. Для этого вы указали: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);`
2. Content-Length должно быть: `strlen('grant_type=password&client_id=$id&username=$login&password=$pass')`
3. grant_type=password - че это ваще? Действуйте согласно документации, благо она на русском языке, так что я вообще не понимаю, в чем могут возникнуть проблемы.

Comment: Если не будет grant_type вылезет ошибка "unsupported_grant_type ― неверное значение параметра grant_type.", это описано в документации.

Comment: Лично я бегло осмотрел документацию не увидел там пункт, где grant_type может принимать значение password

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите работать с $query, ставьте RETURNTRANSFER, 1; `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` - это вообще уберите, если не заработает, отснифайте - увидите, что там передается (`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`).

Comment: не нужно ничего снифать, все отправляемые и получаемые данные можно узнать средствами cURL

Comment: да ладно? как средствами курл узнать что отправлять в POSTFIELDS?

Answer (score 0):

Для получения токена подойдет

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $yandexConfig['oauthUrl']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=password&username=" .$yandexConfig['yandexOauthLogin']. "&password="
        .$yandexConfig['yandexOauthPass']. "&client_id=" .$yandexConfig['metricsAppId']. "&client_secret="
        .$yandexConfig['metricsAppSecret']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $authData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $authDataObj = json_decode($authData);
```

где

- `$yandexConfig['oauthUrl']` - url, по которому пытаемся получить токен
- `$yandexConfig['yandexOauthLogin']` - логин
- `$yandexConfig['yandexOauthPass']` - пароль
- `$yandexConfig['metricsAppId']` - id вашего приложения
- `$yandexConfig['metricsAppSecret']` - секретный ключ приложения